# Why It showing Hello two times try in on Turbo C v 3.0

Tags: c

although the value of NULL 0. explain with good example.

```
void main()
{
  int i;
  for(i=0;NULL;i++)
  {
     printf("Hello");
  }
  printf("Hello");
}
```

Comment: It doesn't - one time only

Comment: Where are your `#include <stdlib.h>` and `#include <stdio.h>`?

Comment: I tried in turbo c v3.0. and you also try it

Comment: wow... this is great

Comment: That is very curiously strange output to receive. Since NULL is a constant expression it should either loop never *or* loop forever. The code looping once disagrees with this observation and is thus .. suspect. Verify the file has been recompiled, the output terminal is clear, and that the code shown is accurate.

Comment: Turbo C is quite old and not many folks have it to try. What do you get in the same function (without changing anything else) if you do, `printf("NULL = %d\n", NULL);`? Also make sure you are showing the code here that you actually executed.

Comment: M writing same code. printf("NULL = %d\n", NULL); is giving 0, I understand. please copy above code and run in turbo 3.0

Comment: @KailashKarki like I said in my prior comment. Turbo C 3.0 is very old and few folks have it. I do not. To me, it would appear to be a bug in the way Turbo C 3.0 handles the `for` loop if this is really what you're seeing. Try turning off any code optimization options if you have any set and see if the results are the same.

Comment: @KailashKarki it would be easier for you to run it using a newer compiler than expect everyone else to use a depreciated compiler.

Comment: 1997 era TURBO -C compiler still used?

Comment: Some very old compilers defined `NULL` to be `-1`. It could explain the fact he got in the loop and `printf()` called two times. But I don't know if it's the case of Turbo C although.

Comment: @Jack How can -1 (for the sake of argument) pass the conditional test once, but fail it the second test? This appears to be a bug that exists outside of a logical explanation (at the C level).

Comment: Sorry. I read it quickly and wrong. I read `i=NULL` instead of `i=0`.

Comment: (and then after `i++` value is `i = 0` and the loop ran only once)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a well-known bug in the Turbo C 3.0 compiler.

But note one thing: currently the behaviour of your function is undefined as `main` should always have an `int` return type. Formally, a standards compliant compiler is permitted to do anything with your program!

If you adjust your program so it has no undefined constructs then, on a standard compliant compiler, it will be guaranteed to output "hello" exactly once.

Comment: I don't think it's allowed for NULL to evaluate to 1. But even if it did, the loop would run infinitely.

Comment: `main`'s return is unneeded. And, anything else than 0 is true.

Comment: @Quentin: No, it's undefined behaviour to not have `int` as the return type.

Comment: @Bathsheba you're right about the return type, but I mean the `return` statement itself :)

Comment: @lurker: you're correct of course. I've amended.

Comment: People, this is Turbo-C 3.0, which is extremely old, well before any real standards existed. Here, it doesn't matter whether `main` returns an `int` or not. That should have no effect.

Comment: So simply defining main to return `int` "fixes" this bug?

Comment: Probably not but it certainly means the behaviour of the program is defined.